# Add css for class

Tags: css

I have original CSS from example 
       CSS:

```
a.blink, a:hover.blink {
    color: white;
}

span.blink {
    animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}

<span style="background-color: red" class="blink">
    <a href="./?np&id={$i->id}" target="_blank" class="blink">
        #{$i->id}
    </a>
</span>
```

How i can use this style for "records" class?

```
  <div class="records">
     <a class="blink" href="index.php?id=494172" target="_blank">#494172</a> 
  </div>
```

And my test CSS

```
div.records a.blink, div.records a.hover.blink {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more details? What is happening now and what is the desired result?

Comment: did you set the animation also for `div.records`? is that all the CSS? Could you show the issue with a runnable snippet?

Comment: Now i have only bacground color ("red"). Blink not work.

Comment: You have `a.hover` in the bottommost css block, which I believe should be `a:hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this to your CSS:

```
.records .blink,
.records .hover.blink {
  color: white;
}

.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/um9a0L7d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to css

```
div.records { animation: blinker 1s linear infinite; background-color: red; }
```